# insert into existing row/select non-empty fields

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, insert

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu1MR.png

h i all, as you can see on the picture there is lot of empty fields as result of inserting data (left bottom) only under single column. it is not nice neither very clear

my first question is, while inserting, can i somehow insert that data right under the last data and not as whole new row?

secondly, while using SELECT in query/setModel() in java app is it possible to retrieve just non-empty fields?

code to get data:

```
public void showExports(){  
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(getResultSet("select * from t1")));}
```

code to insert:

```
insert into t1 (`68`) values ('01/04/2020')
```

edit:

table is something like this:

(site doesn't accept more spaces so i'll use "-" so it is more clear)

11---------------14-------------31----------------53------------68 (column headers)

01/04/2020
          -----------03/04/2020

------------------------------------------------02/04/2020

---------------------------05/04/2020

--------------------------------------------------------------01/04/2020

(dates are under column names)

Comment: It's up to you which column you insert to and an insert will always create a new row, if you have a lot of columns that are empty then I would question your design. Secondly yes but not easily. Perhaps a better design for you would be a variation on key value pairs. Can you add your current table schema as text please.

Comment: @P.Salmon added :) maybe  use one column as ID and use UPDATE?

Comment: What meaning to the columns have in relation to the dates in them?

Answer (score 0):

You want an `update`.  Something like this:

```
update t1
    set `68` = '2020-04-01'   -- note correct date format
    where . . . ;
```

The `where` is for the logic that specifies what you mean by "last row".  Typically, this would be something like `id = ?`, where `?` is a parameter to specify the id of the most recently inserted row.

Comment: thanks, yea looks like i'm gonna use UPDATE and i'll add ID column